# Entity Framework Saving Multiple Entities with Collection

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have a loop trying to add two participant entities with its collections

```
foreach (var dto in participants)
{
    var participant = new Participant(dto.FirstName, dto.LastName, dto.Email);
    this.myRepository.Set<Participant>().Add(participant);
    participant.DemographicItems = demographicItems;
}

this.myRepository.SaveChanges();
```

**DemographicItems is a collection**. If we add two participants within this loop the result for DemographicItems table into database will be:

==========================================

## DemographicItemId | Name | ParticipantId |

### 1............................| Age.....| 1...................|

### 2............................| Area... | 1...................|

### 3............................| Age.....  | 1..................|

### 4............................| Area... | 1...................|

As you can see the last column contains only ids for the first inserted participant, the second foreign id value is missing, the right values should be 1,1,2,2, **what I want is to avoid SaveChanges() into the loop for every item**. **I want to perform one single SaveChanges() for all participants and its DemographicItem collections**. This is how the Participant table looks like into the database after insert the two participants.

======================

## ParticipantId | Name |

### 1...................|Tommy.|

### 2...................|Frank...|

Comment: What's the content of `demographicItems`? Existing items from the database to be copied to the new participants, or new items?

Comment: It is only a collection of items with Name and other properties of type string.

Comment: I think You should set all the properties of participant before You are adding it to the context. When debugging - does demographicItems collection holds two rows with id 1 and 2?